# applying different layouts to different views in razor

Tags: asp.net, razor

Currently i'm using this code in my `_viewstart.cshtml` to determine what layout should be applied to different views.

```
if ((ViewContext.View.Path == "/Views/Register/Index.cshtml") 
    || (ViewContext.View.Path == " /Views/Register/Billing.cshtml") 
    || (ViewContext.View.Path == "/Views/Register/Register.cshtml"))
{
    Layout = "_AppLayout";
} else { Layout = "_Layout"; }
```

Is there any other/better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to specify the layout in the view file. In each view, you can add a directive to the top of the view code like so:

```
@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/YourMaster.cshtml"
}
```